# Question about Horners rule algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, algorithms

I am studying Horner's rule I have a question about an algorithm I found [here](http://answers-by-me.blogspot.com/2010/07/clrs-2e-problem-2-3.html) .

I understand that the rule allows you to break down polynomials in to monomials to solve them more easily, so that for example:

```
3x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 5
```

becomes

```
5 + x*(2 + x*(3 + x*(2 + x*(3)))
```

so, the algorithm is (verbatim from the website):

```
   1- NAIVE-POLY-EVAL(P, x):    ▹ Assume P is indexed from zero
   2- y ← 0
   3- for i ← 0 to length(P)
   4-     do ai ← P[i]
   5-         z ← 1
   6-         for j ← 1 to i
   7-             do z ← x·z
   8-         y ← y + ai·z
   9- return y
```

line by line I go through what I think it means and where I'm confused..

1- `P` is the polynomial..is `x` point at which we want to evaluate the polynomial?.

2- set the output variable

3- first loop to go through the polynomial `P`

4- set the `i-th` value of `P` to `a`

5- set `z` as ... first exponential? (looking that it grows with the inner loop)

6- inner loop evaluate the exponentials

7- assign to `z` the right exponential

8- assign to `y` the value of `a` times the exponential `z`

9- and return `y` once all the loops are done

so..if I try to apply it to something like

`(2x - 1) at x = 2`

I should get `3` as an answer...so my questions are:

1) at line 6 the loop starts at `j=1` while `i=0` so that `i` will be always smaller than `y`, how does that work?!

2) is it right that `x` in line 1 is the value at which we want to evaluate the polynomial and `z` in line 5 is the exponential?

thanks!!

Comment: The polynomial $2x-1$ is too small to see clearly what is going on. Try to trace the evaluation of say $2x^3+5x^2+7x+4$.

Comment: The expression you have is wrong. For example, the last part should be $x(2 + x \cdot 3)$.